# What is better ways to store id after successful login?

Tags: django, session, caching, django-rest-framework

For my project, I am using Angular + Django Rest Framework.
I am storing id in local storage (using Angular).

But I want to learn other ways to do it.

Can we use (In Django)

> Session

> Cache

How?

Answer (score 0):

create request.session['id'] in your login view

```
# Create your views here.
```

def login(request):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            userlogin(request, user)
            data = User.objects.filter(username=user).all().values()
            print(data)
            
            request.session['id']=data[0]['id']
            request.session['username']=data[0]['username']
            request.session['displayName']=data[0]['displayName']
            request.session['role']=data[0]['role']
            request.session['mobile']=data[0]['mobile']
            request.session['email']=data[0]['email']
            request.session['company_id']=data[0]['company_id']
            request.session['is_active']=data[0]['is_active']
            request.session['is_staff']=data[0]['is_staff']
            
            return redirect("dashboard")
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "Your account is blocked! Please contact Site Administrator.")
    else:
        messages.warning(request, "Please enter the correct Email address and password!")
return render(request,"login.html")
```

This is mine

Comment: I am using django rest. Can I use the above for APIs also? Because we return only JSON data through Response().

Comment: yes you do it with API also, you have to get values from your API and make it request.session